# iOS 7 undo redo icons: use them or the default text?

Tags: icons, ios7

What are folks doing for undo/redo buttons in iOS 7?  The `UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo` now displays only text for the buttons.  I was an "Apple knows best" person until iOS 7.  My app will be iOS 7 only so I don't need to be concerned with backward compatibility.

I'm really fighting the urge to at least put line icons on the toolbar instead of the iOS defaults.  What should I do?

1. Be a good citizen and let the iOS decide
2. Make my own artistic choice and go with icons.  If so:

   2a. What style (line, old school icon)?

   2b. What shape (part circle, curved arrows, line arrows)?

Answer (score 2):

Do what you think is clearer to the user.

iOS 7 buttons and icons may look poor, but they are great to minimize clogging a view when you need to display many controls that leave little free space to show useful info.
There are lots of iOS 7 icons for free.

- Apple's "Bar Button Icons",
- [Pixeden tab-bar icons](http://www.pixeden.com/media-icons/tab-bar-icons-ios-7),
- [Icons8](http://icons8.com/free-ios-7-icons-in-vector/), etc.

You may find useful the redo icon displayed at Icons8. By flipping it you may obtain easily the undo icon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Antonio. Your answer makes the case for icons vs ios7 text buttons for undo and redo when you say you want more room for useful info.  Obviously, icons take way less room than the text undo and redo.